# Match word and proceeding characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings in this format

```
{a}| {match} {b} {c}
{a} {b}: {match} {c}
{a} {b}: {c} -{match}
```

I want to find the word {match} and all proceeding characters until the previous }. My desired output would be this:

```
{a} {b} {c}
{a} {b} {c}
{a} {b}: {c}
```

I have tried this regex, but that matches from the first }, and not the proceeding

```
(\})(.*)({match})
```

Comment: `\}([^}]*)({match})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
[^}]+{match}
```

- `[^}]+` Negated character set. Anything other than a `}`, one or more.
- `{match}` Literal substring `{match}`.

Replacing with nothing:

```js
var s = '{a}| {match} {b} {c}'
var t = '{a} {b}: {c} -{match}'

console.log(s.replace(/[^}]+{match}/g, ""));
console.log(t.replace(/[^}]+{match}/g, ""));
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/LNv140/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could match what you want and capture in a group what you don't want. In the replacement use group 1.

[`[^{}]+{match\}|(\{[^}]+\})`](https://regex101.com/r/od4igG/1)

```js
const regex = /[^{}]+{match\}|(\{[^}]+\})/g;
const str = `{a}| {match} {b} {c}
{a} {b}: {match} {c}
{a} {b}: {c} -{match}`;
const subst = `$1`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```